# получить цвет заливки ячейки в Excel файле

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

есть файл, который состоит с милиона строк его нужно пропарсить.
что я собственно и сделал, но есть еще задача по проверке цвета заливки в этой ячейке.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb_form = load_workbook("1.xlsx", data_only=True)
sheet_form = wb_form["1"]
wb = sheet_form["B2"].value
f = open("1.txt", "w+")
tmp = 0

for iter, row in enumerate(sheet_form.values):
    if iter == 0:
        continue
    for i in row:
         if i == None:
             continue
         print(i)




f.close()
```

не могу найти решение.
как в момент итерации проверять цвет ячейки?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55122922/get-the-color-of-a-cell-from-xlsx-with-python

Comment: вы хотите проверять цвет в каком-то определенном столбце или во всем листе?

Comment: я записываю каждую ячейку в txt файл через ";" , но если цвет ячейки желтый или красный то нужно умножить это число на чило n,
вообщем перебрать каждую ячейку и записать ее в файл при условии если она не помечена цветом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [73]: from openpyxl import load_workbook
    ...:
    ...: wb = load_workbook(r"C:\Temp\1.xlsx")
    ...: ws = wb["Sheet1"]
    ...:
    ...: for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=5):
    ...:     for cell in row:
    ...:         print(f"coordinate: {cell.coordinate}\tvalue: {cell.value}\tcolor: {cell.fill.start_color.index}")
    ...:
coordinate: A1  value: a        color: 00000000
coordinate: B1  value: b        color: 00000000
coordinate: C1  value: c        color: 00000000
coordinate: A2  value: 1        color: 00000000
coordinate: B2  value: 2        color: FFC6EFCE
coordinate: C2  value: 3        color: 00000000
coordinate: A3  value: 4        color: 00000000
coordinate: B3  value: 5        color: FFFFC7CE
coordinate: C3  value: 6        color: 00000000
coordinate: A4  value: 7        color: 00000000
coordinate: B4  value: 8        color: FFFFEB9C
coordinate: C4  value: 9        color: 00000000
coordinate: A5  value: 10       color: 00000000
coordinate: B5  value: 11       color: 5
coordinate: C5  value: 12       color: 00000000
```

Comment: Спасибо) ты лучший!